# What's the measure of the $\angle PBN$ in the question below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference (exact copy of question): In the acute triangle $ABC$, the heights AH and BN are plotted. Extended H intersects the circumcircle at $P$.
Calculate $\angle PBN$ if $\angle AON=30^\circ.$ $O$ is the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$.
(answer $120^\circ$)

My progress: Here is the picture I made and the relationships found. I drew some auxiliary lines...

[image]

$D$ is circumcenter

$ABPC$ is cyclic $\implies \angle PAB = \angle PCB\\
\angle BDA = \angle NAP=60^o=\angle NBC$

Comment: $\angle OAN=60^{\circ}.$ So $ABC$ cannot be equilateral.

Comment: @SathvikAcharya..thanks for alert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\angle HBO=90^{\circ}-\angle BOH=90^{\circ}-\angle AON=60^{\circ}$$
Since $ABPC$ is cyclic,
$$\angle PBC=\angle PAC=90^{\circ}-\angle AON=60^{\circ}$$
Therefore,
$$\angle PBN=\angle PBC+\angle CBN=\boxed{120^{\circ}}$$